# Problema al usar CrystalReport para crear PDF en Visual Studio, imprimen todos los valores menos los que son String

Tags: visual-studio, mvc, pdf, crystal-reports

Quiero hacer que mi proyecto web de la opción de exportar un PDF el cual logré, al seleccionar a unos empleados en una lista, crea un PDF con su información pero los datos que son valor string no los muestra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver, esos son los valores que saco de un procedimiento almacenado. Al colocar la vista previa del PDF aparecen todos los datos bien pero cuando se exporta desaparecen los strings. Muchas Gracias.